# custom chart design with angled edges

Tags: html, css, charts

[here is the full image with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYIzr.png)   I need to create a dynamic chart that displays test results. Problem - this is not a usual bar chart - the bars are displayed in angle (like this image1). With css transform skew property I was able to get the slanted effect (image2), however i have 2 issues now:
1) With dynamic results - when the height of the bar changes, then the bar tends to position differently (refer image3)
2) How do I position the legend (percentage text) to the bars with dynamic heights

```
.resultBar {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 9;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.resultBar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: skew(-35deg);
  background: #e43d30;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}
.whiteBar::before {
  background: #e6e8e9;
  height: 50%;

}
```

20%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the transform is being originated from the middle of the element. use transform-origin to determine the position from which it should originate. here is an example:

```css
.bars {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 9;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  
}
.bar {
  background: #f00;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  transform: skew(-35deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bars">
  <div class="bar" style="height: 20%"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 30%"></div>
  <div class="whitebar bar" style="height: 10%"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 50%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! thanks a ton!! any idea on how to display those  percentage numbers above the bars?

Comment: yes, you can do something like this - https://codepen.io/urich/pen/zgzZyE